# joomla, html + javascript, radio button validation

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, breezingforms

Hi i need to make a  html form with a number of questions, each question has 3 answers an each answer is a radio button , the thing is : each answer has a value which goes from 0 to 2, so answer 1 is equal to 0, answer 2 to 1, answer 3 to 2, i need to get the valué of the radio button selected because later i will use it to show an answer, for example : do you like helping people ? radio button 1 : never, radio button 2: sometimes, radio button 3: always, then after you answer lets say 10 questions i will show your results on screen like this : you got 5 points you are a great person for example. I think this can be made with html with javascript but i dont know the javascript stuff, can you help me telling me how to do that ?? , thanks.

Comment: You should be either using the breezing forms documentation for this or switch to using the Joomla forms API which is best discussed at the stack exchange site devoted to Joomla [joomla.se].

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSForm!Pro for this, which will allow you to easily create the form. You will be able to modify the "Thank You" message to include the answers provided by the end user. For example, if you have a field named `answer1` in your form, then you can just retrieve the field's value using `{answer1:value}` in the "Thank You" message.